# find and stop specific service in Android

Tags: android, android-service

I read in Professional Android 4 Application Development book:
"Calls to startService do not nest, so a single call to stopService will terminate the running
Service it matches, no matter how many times startService has been called."

Does that mean that if I start two separate services of the same kind, it will terminate both when calling stopService? Or does it stop the first it finds?

I create an IntentService which creates an Alarm to go off at a certain time. It's possible to delete an Alarm before it goes off. How can I find the right Service, in order to stop it?

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {

public static final String CREATE = "CREATE";
public static final String CANCEL = "CANCEL";

private IntentFilter matcher;

public AlarmService() {
    super("ctor AlarmService");
    matcher = new IntentFilter();
    matcher.addAction(CREATE);
    matcher.addAction(CANCEL);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String notificationId = intent.getStringExtra("notificationId");

    if (matcher.matchAction(action)) {          
        execute(action, notificationId);
    }
}

private void execute(String action, String notificationId) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ReminderContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, "_id = ?", new String[]{notificationId}, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ReminderColumns.ADDRESS)) == null)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            i.putExtra("id", c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(ReminderColumns._ID)));
            i.putExtra("msg", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ReminderColumns.TITLE)));

            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 
                                                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            long time = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(ReminderColumns.DATE));
            if (CREATE.equals(action)) {
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pi);

            } else if (CANCEL.equals(action)) {
                am.cancel(pi);
            }
        }
    }
    c.close();      
}
```

}

MainActivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmService.class);
intent.setAction(AlarmService.CREATE);
intent.putExtra("notificationId", idStr);
startService(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean that if I start two separate services of the same kind, it will terminate both when calling stopService? Or does it stop the first it finds?

If by "kind" you mean "class", then the answer is "neither, as there is only one instance of the service in the first place".

> How can I find the right Service, in order to stop it?

Your `IntentService` will be running for less than a millisecond, so there is nothing really to stop. An `IntentService` automatically calls `stopSelf()` (the in-service equivalent of `stopService()`) when `onHandleIntent()` returns, assuming no new commands were sent to the service via `startService()` in the meantime.

Comment: sorry, I completely misunderstood that. I'm trying to implement a reminder app according to this example: http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/remindme/2/#7

I guess I don't really have to use a service to start the alarms with the AlarmManager.

If I would start the alarms directly, would they still go off when the app closes or if the phone restarts?

Comment: @user2246120: "If I would start the alarms directly, would they still go off when the app closes or if the phone restarts?" -- if the app closes, `AlarmManager` alarms are still in effect, unless you cancel them yourself (or the user uses Force Stop in Settings to nuke you from orbit). On a reboot, though, the `AlarmManager` roster is wiped clean. A typical approach is to set up an `BOOT_COMPLETED` `BroadcastReceiver` to re-establish your alarms.

Comment: but why is he using a service in the example above? Is there another advantage to using a service?

Comment: @user2246120: "but why is he using a service in the example above?" -- I have no clue. Setting an alarm is cheap and should not cause a problem if done on the main application thread. Even if you were concerned about that, a quick-and-dirty background thread would seem sufficient. Now, doing work when an alarm *occurs* may require a service, as that might take some time.